# При автозагрузке программа убивается

Tags: c#, консоль, исключения, файловая-система, автозагрузка

Приветствую,

Добавляю консольную программу в автозагрузку таким способом

```
        if ( this.autorun != 0 )
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Key =
                Microsoft
                .Win32
                .Registry
                .CurrentUser
                .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", true);

            Key.SetValue("имя_программы", Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\имя_программы.exe");
            Key.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key =
                Microsoft
                .Win32
                .Registry
                .CurrentUser
                .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", true);

            key.DeleteValue("имя_программы", false);
            key.Close();
        }
```

На Win7 работает правильно - после загрузки системы программа запускается и выполняет свою работу.

Проблема возникает на Win Vista - после загрузки системы программа запускается, но после этого кидает исключение. В логах пусто, тут закрались подозрения, сделал вывод в консоль и подозрения подтвердились - эксепшн вылетает при первой попытке записать в файл.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Windows\system32\error.log".
```

`error.log` - собственно, файл логов. Почему-то пытается писать в `C:\Windows\system32\`. Сначала подумал на относительные пути, но при указании абсолютных - абсолютно то же самое. При ручном запуске всё в норме.

Непонятно куда копать.

---

@Pavel Mayorov

```
StreamWriter f = new StreamWriter( Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "error.log", true );
f.WriteLine( str );
f.Close();
```

Comment: Зачем вы так подробно расписали механизм автозапуска? Напишите лучше, как вы открываете файл лога.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov: добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "error.log"` - это вы называете "абсолютным путем"?! Очевидно же, что текущая директория "по умолчанию" - `C:\Windows\system32\`. Вот и файл лога оказывается там.

Где лучше разместить файл лога? Для приложений, которые ставятся в `Program Files` лучше всего размещать его где-нибудь в неперемещаемом профиле пользователя. Путь к нему можно получить как `Enviroment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`.

Если же приложение является portable (т.е. предназначено для запуска из директории с доступом на запись) - то хорошей отправной точкой будет `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` или же `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`.

Comment: Хм, странно, почему-то думал, что `Environment.CurrentDirectory` всегда возвращает текущую директорию с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: @froxxendsg: У каждого процесса есть текущий каталог. Если процесс запускают из каталога, где он находится (так чаще всего и бывает), и он не меняет свой текущий каталог (так бывает тоже достаточно часто), то текущий каталог — это и есть каталог программы.

Comment: @froxxendsg: В любом случае, писать в System32 или Program Files — очень плохая идея. Слава богу, начиная с Vista операционка никому этого так просто не разрешает.

Comment: @VladD: естественно не собирался писать в System32 или Program Files

Comment: @VladD:   Экзешник находится на другом диске и пишет все логи в свою директорию. После автозагрузки почему-то `Environment.CurrentDirectory` содержит не путь до директории с экзешником, а `C:\Windows\system32\ ` . К слову на Win7 относительные пути работали как нужно - писали в директорию с экзешником.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то при автозагрузке процесс запускается из `C:\Windows\system32\ `, независимо от местонахождения экзешника.

Comment: @froxxendsg: (1) Писать логи в каталог программы обычно неправильно. Программа должна быть в защищённом от записи месте, и запускаться не от имени того пользователя (обычно админа), который её устанавливал. (2) Сетевой путь не может быть текущим каталогом. Попробуйте в командном интерпретаторе сделать `cd` на такой каталог.

Comment: @VladD, сетевой путь **может** быть текущим каталогом. То, что на него нельзя сделать `cd` - это ограничение исключительно `cmd.exe`, а не общесистемное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, и правда.