# Проблема с запуском стороннего приложения из консольного на .NET при автозапуске из реестра

Tags: c#, консоль, x86-64

Есть консольное приложение на C#. У него основная задача запускать стороннее приложение(разработанное не на .NET), следить за ним и перезапускать его при определенных условиях.
Запуск стороннего приложения осуществляется кодом:

```
public static bool StartProcess(string path, string arguments = "")
{
    ...

    Process process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = path,
            Arguments = arguments,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
            Verb = "runas"
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    ...
}
```

Само консольное приложение добавляется в автозагрузку в реестр:

```
public static void RegisterWatchdogAutorun(bool register)
{
    using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true))
        {
            string watchdogName = "Watchdog";
            string watchdogValue = string.Concat("\"", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "\"");

            if (register)
            {
                key.SetValue(watchdogName, watchdogValue);
            }
            else
            {
                key.DeleteValue(watchdogName, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Консольное приложение скомпилировано как x64.
Стороннее приложение тоже вроде как x64, но может быть и x86. Windows 10 x64, .NET 4.5.

Если я из проводника или тотала запускаю консольное приложение вручную, оно работает как задумано, при выполнении функции StartProcess сторонний процесс запускается. При перезагрузке компьютера консольное приложение также запускается по пути из реестра и работает. Но как настает этап запуска стороннего приложения, код StartProcess отрабатывает, но стороннее приложение не запускается. При перезапуске консольного приложения из проводника - все начинает работать.

Пробовал использовать прокладку в виде cmd для запуска стороннего приложения из консольного. Не взлетело. Но если отключить автозапуск консольного приложения и сделать его средствами системы минуя реестр - т.е. создать ярлык на него и поместить в автозагрузку, то стороннее приложение начинает запускаться.

Так и не могу понять в чем отличие запуска через ярлык от запуска через реестр, и почему в одном случае стороннее запускается, а в другом - нет. Подразумеваю что проводник или тотал создают специальное окружение, в котором стороннее приложение может запуститься, а я не в курсе про него и как это реализовать.

В чем может быть причина, и как это разрешить в идеале через реестр?

UPDATE:
Проблема решена. Как правильно предположил Pavel Mayorov, использовался относительный путь вместо абсолютного. Функция Path.GetFullPath возвращала разные результаты при загрузке из проводника и после рестарта. Вместо нее лучше использовать Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location в данной ситуации - результат будет одинаковый. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: К сведению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427927/178779

Comment: Дайте я угадаю: в path лежит относительный путь?

Comment: На входе в программу относительный. Затем вызывается path = Path.GetFullPath(sourcePath).
Попробовал на вход в программу жестко задать абсолютный путь. Стороннее приложение начало стартовать.

Comment: ну в этом и проблема

Comment: Осталось узнать почему не отрабатывает Path.GetFullPath. Первый раз вижу это этот метод отрабатывает походу как то не так. Буду разбираться почему.

Comment: а вы почитайте что он делает